# Can't write right to left language in my compute engine instance

Tags: linux, debian, right-to-left, google-compute-engine

I've tried writing a select query in my terminal using a string in right to left language, but couldn't no letter was accepted

I've tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` adding these languages but still trying to type something is not being accepted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1- Log in with root.

2- Install locales

```
apt-get install locales
```

3- See your locales

```
sudo locale -a
```

4- reconfigure locales

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

5- Select your locale

```
en_US.UTF-8
```

you also can use

```
locale-gen
```